# Magento 2.3 - The correct way to get custom attribute

Tags: magento2, model, eav-attributes

I have added the custom attribute `referral_code` of type `static` to the customer entity. The attribute showing up correctly, and I can get/set it in easy way with `$customer->getReferralCode()` and with `$customer->setReferralCode(value)`. But these methods, of course, don't really exist inside the Customer Model (I think that behind the scene there is some magic method). The problem is that in this way I don't have any hint/intellisense by IDE. The others developer, if they don't know the existence about the attribute,don't receive any suggestion by theirs IDE. So, it's "normal" that this happen or I can extend the Customer Base Model and add the get/set methods of my custom attributes? If it's possible to do this, what are the steps to reach it?

Comment: You have raised a good point. +1 for that

Answer (score 0):

This is not the issue, you are doing it correctly, as you already know these are magic function and it has no definitions of their own. But you can add a description of these function on class-level in comment like this:

```
/**
 * @method static someClass setReferralCode(int $ref) Description here
 * @method static someClass getReferralCode() Description here
 */
abstract class a {
...
```

Description [here](https://docs.phpdoc.org/references/phpdoc/tags/method.html)

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15634021/how-to-document-magic-call-and-callstatic-methods-for-ides

Comment: uhm so this is the best way? It's very "ugly" ahaha. Now another question is: where should I add that comment? Because the Customer model is inside the vendor `magento/module-customer`, so I can't edit it. If I have a Block class and I need to call the method `getReferralCode()` I must specify that comment inside my Block class? I have tried it, but it doesn't work (I'm using PHPStorm as IDE).